# javascript quiz to calculate kappa

Tags: javascript

It is clear that I need to learn javascript.  I am trying to write a test that will work offline so I can't use PHP and I am using javascript instead.  Right now I have a test that will give me the score for number of correct answers.  The way I did it was to just add up the values where correct is 1 and incorrect is 0.  So, I can get the number of correct answers.  However, what I really want is to calculate the Kappa score.  To do that I need to know the count for each group in this table:

```
           True
          Y      N
Tester  Y  11    01
        N  10    00
```

here is my quiz:
       
         
         
        test

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function getRBValue(group) { 
        //loop
          for ( var b = 0; b < group.length; ++b ) { 
            if ( group[b].checked ) 
            return Number(group[b].value); 
            } 
            return 0; } 

        function Score(form) { 
            var total = 0; 
            for ( var q = 1; q <= 10; ++q ) { 
            total += getRBValue( form["q"+q] ); 
            } 
        form.score.value = total; 
        alert("You got " + total + " questions right!"); 
        } 

    </script> 

    </head> 
    <body> 


    <h1>test</h1> 

    <p>The following exam will allow you to evaluate your ability to grade Trachoma.</p> 
    </body> 

    <form name="prequiz" onsubmit="Score(this); return false;"> 


    <table cellpadding=15px border="0" width="65%" summary= "Questions and options are organized in a table.">
    <tbody> 
    <tr> <td>
    <b><img src="pics/1.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" > Present<br/> 
    <br/><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/2.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 


    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/3.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/4.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q4" value="0" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q4" value="1" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/5.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q5" value="0" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q5" value="1" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/6.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q6" value="0" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q6" value="1" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/7.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q7" value="0" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q7" value="1" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/8.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q8" value="1" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q8" value="0" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/9.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q9" value="1" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q9" value="0" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr>  

    <tr> 
    <td>
    <b><img src="pics/10.jpeg"</b><br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q10" value="0" > Present<br/> 
    <br/> <input type="radio" name="q10" value="1" > Absent<br/> 
    </td> </tr> 

    </tbody> </table> </center> 

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Score exam now"> 
    <br/><br/>

    <b>Your score:</b><input type="text" name="score" readonly="readonly" />
    <br/>
    </form> </html>
```

Comment: So what's the question, exactly?

Comment: Right now I get a number correct score.  What I need to know is the first table.  How many answers are Absent when the true value is Absent.  How many answers are Absent when the true value is Present.  How many answers are Present when the true value is Present.  How many answers are Present when the true value is Absent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getRBValue`, you loop through the group elements, of which there are always two. The first one is always the Present choice and the second is always the Absent choice. In your current code, you can distinguish these by the value of the loop variable `b`.  However, I would rewrite your code as:

```
var PP, // correct is Present; user answered Present
    PA, // correct is Present; user answered Absent
    PN, // correct is Present; user did not answer
    AP, // correct is Absent; user answered Present
    AA, // correct is Absent; user answered Absent
    AN; // correct is Absent; user did not answer

function ScoreGroup(group) {
    var presentIsCorrect = Number(group[0].value);
    if (group[0].checked) {
        // user answered Present
        if (presentIsCorrect) {
            PP++;
        } else {
            AP++;
        }
    } else if (group[1].checked) {
        // user answered Absent
        if (presentIsCorrect) {
            PA++;
        } else {
            AA++;
        }
    } else {
        // user did not answer the question
        if (presentIsCorrect) {
            PN++;
        } else {
            AN++;
        }
    }
}

function Score(form) { 
    PP = PA = PN = AP = AA = AN = 0;
    for ( var q = 1; q <= 10; ++q ) { 
        ScoreGroup( form["q"+q] ); 
    }
    var totalCorrect = PP + AA;
    // TODO: compute kappa from PP, PA, PN, AP, AA, AN, and totalCorrect
    form.score.value = totalCorrect; 
    alert("You got " + totalCorrect + " questions right!");
}
```

You could accumulate the raw counts in a 2D array, but in my opinion using explicit variables makes for more readable (if more verbose) code.

Comment: @A_Pav - If this solves your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted. Just click on the check mark to the left of the answer. :)